# Running command line on a remote machine using Java

Tags: java, command-line, runtime.exec

Is it possible to run command line on a remote machine (not on the server machine where the application is hosted).

I understand `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("..");` will try to run the script on the server machine. Is my understanding correct and is there a way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec` launches a *process* on the *local* machine, not a remote one. Wether that process represents a command line interface or not will be determined by the executable that's run, and the underlying platform.

In order to invoke processes on remote machines you need to:

- Invoke a remoting type command, like rsh or ssh
- Utilize a remoting third party library, like [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Comment: Well ... I have seen `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` used as part of an attack on a server. It started sh and then piped input/output over a socket to a remote controlling server. That way, the remote server was able to issue commands to the victim server.