# How to execute commands in remote windows machine using Java

Tags: java

How to run command-line or execute external application which is hosted in a remote windows machine using java.

Comment: Do you have ssh installed on the remote machine?

Comment: Y must use kind of protocol, open firewals for this protocol .... question is very broad

Comment: @ZeusNet ssh installed but I'm looking for a generic solution.

Comment: Then you should have a look at RMI.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Java, you need a tool that can connect to remote Windows machine and execute commands . `PsExec` is one such utility. 
Refer link [psexec.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) for more details.

In above link, utility usage is mentioned as below and `cmd` is the command that you wish to execute and arguments are arguments to that command.

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
```

then in Java , you can use something like ,

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir);`

you can populate `cmdarray` as , `cmdarray[0]="cmd.exe"` , `cmdarray[1]="/C"` to launch command prompt on your local machine then `cmdarray[2]="psexec command String"` ( this String you have to construct as per usage described above ) .

you can download and install utility if its missing on your system.

you will be required to use third party APIs if planning to use `SSH` connectivity.

Hope it helps !!

Credit goes to [Programmatically connecting to remote systems](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/programmatically_connecting_to_remote_systems2?lang=en)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329244/running-command-line-on-a-remote-machine-using-java) SO question too.

Comment: Couldn't access rhost:
Access is denied.
While executing the psExec manually.

Comment: I don't know much about that utility , was just explaining that you will need a tool like that. Searching for that error tells me that user ( local or specified in command ) must have admin rights on remote machine.